# Python2.7: ssh.exec_command not executing any command

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

I'm creating an `SSH Channel` to a remote host using `paramiko`.  However, when I try to execute any command using the `ssh_object.exec_command`, the command doesn't seem to get executed.

This function creates my `ssh` handler:

```
def ssh_connect(ip,user,pwd):
    '''
    This function will make an ssh connection to the ip using the credentials passed and return the handler
    Args:
        ip: IP Address of the box into which ssh has to be done
        user: User name of the box to which ssh has to be done
        pass: password of the box to which ssh has to be done
    Returns:
        An ssh handler
    '''
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip, username=user, password=pwd)  
    return ssh
```

And this is where I'm using the handler:

```
ssh_obj = ssh_connect(ip, username, password)
folder = "/var/xyz/images/" + build_number
command = "mkdir " + folder
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh_obj.exec_command(command)
```

When I go to the remote machine, the folder has not got created. Similarly, I tried reading the output of an `ls` command as well. No response arrives when I do `ssh_stdout.read()`.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you please check if there is any log in ssh_stderr ?

Comment: @AlekhyaVemavarapu, how do I check that?

Comment: Try  command="mkdir -p " + folder

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either, @skynyrd.

Comment: And @Alekhya, there's no log present in ssh_stderr

Comment: @RandomlyNamedUser Have you solved your issue?

Comment: @AlexandrNikitin I didn't solve the issue but discovered that the issue is seen when my remote host is running a `freebsd` OS. It always works when my remote host is running `Ubuntu`

Comment: @RandomlyNamedUser I have it on CentOS 7 3.10 kernel and cannot figure out why :(

Answer (score 1):

I encountered with the same problem on CentOS 7 servers using paramiko 2.0.2.
The example from the paramiko github homepage didn't work for me at first: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko#demo

```
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=self.server['host'], username=self.server['username'], password=self.server['password'])
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls')
for line in stdout:
    print '... ' + line.strip('\n')
client.close()
```

After I updated the remote system the example above started to work. But not the code I wrote (similar to OP's code) This put an idea that I need to read the stdout buffer right after the execution. So that I amended the code to do it and it worked. Based on OP's code it could look like

```
ssh_obj = ssh_connect(ip, username, password)
folder = "/var/xyz/images/" + build_number
command = "mkdir " + folder
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh_obj.exec_command(command)
# Read the buffer right after the execution:
ssh_stdout.read()
```

What's interesting is that reading the buffer later (after you close the client) gives you nothing.

Answer (score 0):

After the `ssh_exec_command` line; add the below condition.

The loop will exit only after the command(shell) gets fully executed.

`while int(stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()) != 0: time.sleep(1)`